# jade-pdf-redline cannot read property 'length' of undefined node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf-generation, pug

When I want generate a PDF with jade-pdf-redline from my jade template, I have this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined on line 12
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/var/www/html/BP_webApp/node_modules/jade-pdf-redline/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:160:8), <anonymous>:62:26)
at res (/var/www/html/BP_webApp/node_modules/jade-pdf-redline/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:161:38)
at Stream.end (/var/www/html/BP_webApp/node_modules/jade-pdf-redline/lib/index.js:31:18)
at _end (/var/www/html/BP_webApp/node_modules/jade-pdf-redline/node_modules/through/index.js:65:9)
at Stream.stream.end (/var/www/html/BP_webApp/node_modules/jade-pdf-redline/node_modules/through/index.js:74:5)
at Stream.onend (stream.js:59:10)
at emitNone (events.js:85:20)
at Stream.emit (events.js:179:7)
at drain (/var/www/html/BP_webApp/node_modules/jade-pdf-redline/node_modules/through/index.js:34:23)
at Stream.stream.queue.stream.push (/var/www/html/BP_webApp/node_modules/jade-pdf-redline/node_modules/through/index.js:45:5)
at Stream.end (/var/www/html/BP_webApp/node_modules/jade-pdf-redline/node_modules/through/index.js:15:35)
at _end (/var/www/html/BP_webApp/node_modules/jade-pdf-redline/node_modules/through/index.js:65:9)
at Stream.stream.end (/var/www/html/BP_webApp/node_modules/jade-pdf-redline/node_modules/through/index.js:74:5)
at Stream.method [as end] (/var/www/html/BP_webApp/node_modules/jade-pdf-redline/node_modules/duplexer/index.js:47:39)
at ReadStream.onend (_stream_readable.js:491:10)
at ReadStream.g (events.js:273:16)
at emitNone (events.js:85:20)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:179:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:906:12)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:475:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:389:17)
```

index.js

```
conn.query("SELECT * FROM tblForm", function(err, rows) {
     if (err) {
        console.log('Error selecting: %s', err);
     }

     for (var i in rows) {
        console.log('Post: ', rows[i]);
     }

     res.render('form', {
        title: 'titlw',
        rows: rows
     });   

     fs.createReadStream('views/form.jade').pipe(jadepdf()).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('form.pdf'));

  });
```

form.jade

```
- for(var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
                div
                    label Programme
                    input(style='float: right; clear: both; width: 300px;' value='#{rows[i].programme}')
                div
                    br
                    label Action Type
                    input(style='float: right; clear: both; width: 300px;' value='#{rows[i].actionType}')
                div
                    br
                    label Call
                    input(style='float: right; clear: both; width: 300px;' value='#{rows[i].callCell}')
                div
                    br
                    label Language
                    input(style='float: right; clear: both; width: 300px;' value='#{rows[i].lang}')
            - }
```

That API cannot read this line - for(var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) { . Have you any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should pass `rows` variable in `jadepdf()` function.

```
var options = {
   "locals": {
      "rows": rows  
    }
};

fs.createReadStream('views/form.jade').pipe(jadepdf(options)).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('form.pdf'));
```

Because, when `jadepdf` tries to convert it into `.pdf`, jade template has null values of `rows`.